# Null Date return 1900-01-01

Tags: sql, sql-server

If `[ADRCBook Details].RCBDate`column is NULL; I move `[Transaction Details].TDJournalDate`column instead of that.

```
isnull(convert(date,[ADRCBook Details].RCBDate,112),isnull(convert(date,[Transaction Details].TDJournalDate,112),''))
```

Part of the query I mention above. My problem is I get 1900-01-01. I need blank ('') if both of the columns are NULL.

Comment: `''` is not a date, so you cannot have that value in a `date` datatype

Comment: What is the method to move  ' ' when both date is NULL.

Comment: If both dates are NULL, it would make most sense (to me, but I don't know what you are trying to do here), to return NULL. By the way, you might want to look at [COALESCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Why are you using `convert(date`? You don't need with date fields. You only need that if you stored dates in string fields, in which case you have a *major* bug. You have no way of knowing what's stored in those fields. And `''` isn't a date so you *really* can't use it in any date-typed expression. It just makes no sense.

Comment: Why do you want a blank? Are you trying to affect how a *client* behaves by changing the query results? It would be a *lot* better to modify the client and have it display nothing if the value is null. Which is probably what that client already does. You could replace all of this with `ISNULL(RCBDate,TDJournalDate)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you need:

```
isnull(cast(convert(date, isnull([ADRCBook Details].RCBDate, [Transaction Details].TDJournalDate), 112) as varchar), '')
```

Of course instead of `cast` you can use `convert`. The main point is to discard the `date` type information.

Comment: @Mark why are you storing strings instead of dates in the first place? And why do you want to return an arbitrary string instead of null? You could replace this code with `ISNULL(RCBDate,TDJournalDate)` if you used the correct type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos most probably he wants to use that string in some kind of formatted string result as part of some sentence, or whatever string he needs by requirements.

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev which is easier to do with a `null`. Clients will format that null as an empty string. Datepickers and other UI elements will just ignore it. They won't be able to handle both dates and empty strings without extra parsing though, which introduces localization problems.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know these issues, I am just giving some possible use cases (like ready formatted string result from SQL level to be used in some kind of scripts or automation of data reporting, monitoring, or whatever is the case he need formatted string comes out from database layer), don't know what exactly he is trying to do.

Comment: @MiroslavPenchev the point is to get the OP to understand the issues and how to fix them